# Create a SSH shell using PHP and execute 'powershell.exe'?

Tags: php, ssh, phpseclib

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.106.240.212');
$ssh->login('Administrator', 'Nbv12345') or die("Login failed");
echo $ssh->exec('powershell.exe');
echo connected;
?>
```

I am trying to execute 'powershell.exe' using PHP SSH2. The script **timeouts after 30 seconds** always.

I am able to SSH through a normal SSH client

[image]

While I am able to execute simple commands like

```
dir
```

How can I enter powershell and execute a command ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to either enable a PTY or use an interactive shell. eg.

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.106.240.212');
$ssh->login('Administrator', 'Nbv12345') or die("Login failed");
$ssh->write("powershell.exe\n");
$ssh->setTimeout(2);
echo $ssh->read();
//$ssh->write("dir\n");
//$ssh->read('[prompt]');
?>
```

...or:

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('10.106.240.212');
$ssh->login('Administrator', 'Nbv12345') or die("Login failed");
$ssh->enablePTY()
$ssh->exec("powershell.exe\n");
$ssh->setTimeout(2);
echo $ssh->read();
//$ssh->write("command\n");
//$ssh->read('[prompt]');
?>
```

Comment: Works! output is unreadable. Kindly let me know how the write(),read() works, I shall mark this as the correct answer.

`(B)0[?7l[H[J[1;1H [2;1H [3;1H [4;1H [5;1H [6;1H [7;1H [8;1H [9;1H [10;1H [11;1H [12;1H [13;1H [14;1H [15;1H [16;1H [17;1H [18;1H [19;1H [20;1H [21;1H [22;1H [23;1H [24;1H [1;1HMicrosoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600][2;1H(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.[4;1HC:\Users\Administrator>powershell.exe[5;1H`

Comment: Those are ANSI escape codes. They represent things like color and what not. http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/ssh/examples.html#top discusses how they might be removed.